# highlight the current page in menu in php

Tags: php, html, css, highlight

I would like to highlight active page in menu using php. The page is in static version only common files are called using include in php i.e header.php,footer.php,navigation.php

**navigation.php**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
// Including Files
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/navigation.php');
?> Rest HTML code goes here
```

Comment: You have active class on the list, use CSS to do the highlighting?

Answer (score 12):

**PHP**

```
$activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'index') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'contact-us') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditional statement in each li class attribute in navigation.php file. Use the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] predefined variable, for example for Contact link:

```
<li class="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === '/contact-us.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add proper classes in the every page's `<li>` element and then later highlight the corresponding page button with some CSS.

Code example:

**navigation.php**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="index"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**index.php**

```
// after php includes
<head>
    .index {
        color:red;
    }
</head>
```

**contact-us.php**

```
// after php includes
<head>
    .contact {
        color:red;
    }
</head>
```

...and so on.

Answer (score -1):

you could use the following:

```css
.active, .home:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="home active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You give the links an `ID` like `#activeHome` and `#activeContact`.

```
<li><a href="index.php" id="activeHome">Home</a></li>
```

Then you change in the `HTML` you only load at `Home` for example the `background`.

```
<style>
    #activeHome {
        background:blue;
    }
</style>
```

On the page `Contact` the corresponding.